# Adding a number to a field according to some specific condition

Tags: t-sql

I have the Following Data

```
CompId PersonelNo EduId RecordsDay DateEs
 1      1000        1       2       1370
 1      1000        2       10      1370
 1      1002        2       5       1380
 1      1003        1       4       1391
 1      1003        2       7       1391
```

I want to add (1392-1390=2) for RecordsDay of the Maximum EduID and Records which DateEs are less than or equal to 1390 and add (DateEs -1390) for RecordsDay the Maximum EduID and Records with DateEs Bigger than 1390

So the Data would be like this

```
 CompId PersonelNo EduId RecordsDay DateEs
  1      1000        1       2       1370 // record is the same becuase eduID is not Max for this Personel
  1      1000        2       12      1370 // this is max EduId for this personel and DateEs is less than 1390 so (1392-1390) +10 = 12
  1      1002        2       7       1380 //this is the only record for this personel and DateEs is less than 1390(1392-1390) +5 = 7
  1      1003        1       4       1391 // record is the same becuase eduID is not Max for this Personel
  1      1003        2       8       1391 // this is max EduId for this personel and DateEs is Greater than 1390 so (1391-1390) +7 = 8
```

I want to have TSQl for it. I am working on it, but can write it up to now

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN [EduId] = MAX(EduId) OVER (Partition by PersonelNo) AND DateEs <= 1390 THEN RecordsDay + 2 
    WHEN [EduId] = MAX(EduId) OVER (Partition by PersonelNo) AND DateEs > 1390 THEN RecordsDay + (DateEs -1390) END
```